# Record only last data in a txt file

Tags: c#

I`m trying to reproduce a code example from the book, where the program calculates squares of provided numbers, shows results in cmd, and also record the results in txt.file. For provided numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 the program can calculate results and show them in cmd as:

```
1
4
9
16
```

However, when it needs to record the results in the txt file, it only records 16. I`m not sure if it overrides the previous data or just recording the last squared number. I would like to have a hint what is wrong here and how I can fix it to be able to record all results, just like in cmd.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Chapter4Practice
{
    public interface ITransformer
    {
        int Transform(int x);
    }
    public class Util
    {
        public static void TransformAll(int[] values, ITransformer t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                values[i] = t.Transform(values[i]);
        }
    }

    public class Squarer : ITransformer 
    {
        public int Transform(int x) => x * x;
    }
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            Util.TransformAll(values, new Squarer());
                
            foreach (int i in values)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                WriteProgressToFile(i.ToString());
             } 
        }
        static void WriteProgressToFile(string i) => System.IO.File.WriteAllText("progress.txt", i.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.WriteAllText` method creates a new file, and writes the content to the file.
If existing it is overwritten.
Try to use `File.AppendAllText` which appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exists.

Your method `WriteProgressToFile` will look like the following:

```
static void WriteProgressToFile(string i) => System.IO.File.AppendAllText("progress.txt", i.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: Making sens. Thank you for answer.

Comment: If it helped, please mark the solution as correct. thanks!